# Is the Firefox browser 64-bit on Mac OS X or is the Java website inaccurate?

Tags: macos, firefox, google-chrome, 64-bit, java

On the [Java download page for Mac OS X](https://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp), it says:

> Chrome does not support Java 7. Java 7 runs only on 64-bit browsers and Chrome is a 32-bit browser.
>
> If you download Java 7, you will not be able to run Java content in Chrome and will need to use a 64-bit browser (such as Safari or Firefox) to run Java content within a browser. Additionally, installing Java 7 will disable the ability to use Apple Java 6 on your system.
>
> [I understand the above and want to download Java 7 for Mac OS X (10.7.3 and above).](http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=78698)

Since when is Firefox a 64-bit browser?

Comment: There are 64-bit versions of Firefox they are just not being maintained by Mozilla at this current time ( their focus moved away from this for some reason ). Furthermore the statement is not a percise statement notice that use of `such as` they were only examples. In reality your only other choice likely is Safari. Of course Chromnium can also be compile to be a 64-bit browser.

Comment: Apple is unique in that it does not all 32-bit software on a 64-bit operating system to a certain degree it seems.  Furthermore the last statement is just funny, of course installing Version 7 of the Java SDK should disable Version 6 of the SDK.

Comment: @Ramhound: that is the Windows's 64 bit version of Firefox be abandoned, not Linux and Mac. Currently all Mac apps are 64 bit. You can have a look at [firefox repository](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/)

Comment: I said as much minus the typo in my second comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox for OS X indeed is 64-bit. From the build info:

```
clang -arch x86_64
```

Go to `about:buildconfig` to check it:

> [image]

This has been the case since version 4.0, [according to a mozillaZine mod](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/963358).